# Finding the domain of a difficult inverse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

> $f(x)=\frac{3x+5}{-6x+2}$ , largest possible domain

Find $f^{-1}(x)$ of this 1-1 function and the domain.

So I wrote the equation as

$$y=\frac{3x+5}{-6x+2}$$

Interchanged x and y, and made y the subject (usual method to find the inverse function) and I got :

$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{2x-5}{6x+3}$$

The problem I have is finding the domain of this. The only value that this function breaks apart is when

$$6x+3=0 \implies x=-\frac{1}{2}$$

So therefore I think the domain is :

$$\left(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2}\right)\bigcup \left(-\frac{1}{2},\infty\right)$$

But this answer is wrong. Please help me.

Comment: What is the answer given?

Comment: Are you sure they do not mean to ask you for the domain of $f(x)$ not $f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: @MatthewLevy I am sure....

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I do not know the answer...but I know this is wrong coz its an online Maple question

Comment: @MatthewLevy, here is the exact question : Domain of $ f^{−1}(x)$. Enter this as a disjoint union of intervals. For example, to enter the numbers whose absolute value is greater than 1, you would enter (-infinity,-1)U(1,infinity)

Comment: I think your answer is correct then.

Comment: you found the domain of the inverse , which is the range of f, right?

Comment: @MatthewLevy problem is my answer is wrong

Comment: It's a mobius transformation that sends real line plus infinity to real line plus infinity. This is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is $\left(-\infty,\frac{1}{3}\right)\bigcup \left(\frac{1}{3},\infty\right)$ because of the denominator's restriction.  Likewise, the range of $f$ is $\left(-\infty,\frac{-1}{2}\right)\bigcup \left(\frac{-1}{2},\infty\right)$ because both numerator and denominator are degree 1 which means horizontal asymptotes occur at $y=\frac{3}{-6}=-\frac1{2}$. Since it is a 1-1 function, the domain of $f$ is the range of $f^{-1}$ and the range of $f$ is the domain of $f^{-1}$.  I don't see the issue and believe that you are correct.

Comment: If there is one thing that this site has shown me, it's that mistakes are everywhere.  Sound mathematical reasoning and knowledge of your craft shows the truth, regardless of all...all the textbooks I've learned from have had some error, minor or major.  Nobody is perfect, but logical arguments with precise definitions and mechanics will ultimately lead the user to the answers.